# Steam game doesn't get added to library or start download

Tags: steam

I was trying to download a steam game, which when I click the install button from the app page, launches the steam wizard to install it, however nothing actually happens after the wizard closes.  It appears neither in the library or within the downloads.

This happens if I try from within the Steam client or my browser and launching the steam:// link

I have tried running Steam as a admin, I repaired Steam using the Steam installer, I repaired steam using the steamservice.exe /repair function, I tried renaming the ClientRegistry.blob file to have steam rebuild the file.

Comment: Which game is it?

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Uninstall just the `Games for Windows - LIVE` client through the computer control panel.
> 3. Reinstall just the `Games for Windows - LIVE` client from [this link](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient)
> 4. Reinstall `Age of Empires Online` from within the `Games for Windows - LIVE` client.
> 5. Navigate to the directory where you installed the game and run the `launcher.exe` file as an administrator.

Reference: [Steam forum](http://steamcommunity.com/app/105430/discussions).